# How to show changelogs for packages before upgrade via apper or apt-get upgrade?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, upgrade

Apparently [Debian 9.2 was released today](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/2017/msg00007.html) and due to that Discover and Apper are showing many packages that need to get updated.

I'd like to view a changelog for all of those packages before running the updates.

If possible I'd like to have Apper / Discover go through the packages <sup>(or package-bundles)</sup> one by one so that it shows me a changelog <sup>(potentially along with other information such as user-confirmations for nonmaliciousness and authenticity of the package-update or user-ratings for the changes or links to the closed issues)</sup> and asks for my confirmation to update the respective package <sup>(or package-bundle)</sup>.

But for a start it would be good enough if I could view a changelog for all packages to be upgraded in the terminal after running `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

How can this be done? I already tried it with `apt-listchanges` which was recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272215/seeing-apt-get-changelogs-for-to-be-upgraded-packages).

I'm running Debian 9 with KDE.

Answer (score 9):

You’ve got part of the answer already: the tool for this is `apt-listchanges`. By default it only shows important notifications, from `NEWS.Debian`, not the full changelogs; to see the latter you need to configure it by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt-listchanges
```

and asking it to prompt after displaying changes, and selecting “both” when it asks you which changes to show.

Once that’s done, upgrades (using `apt`, `apt-get` or `aptitude`) will download the packages, extract the changelogs, display them (using your pager of choice, which is also configurable), and ask for confirmation before proceeding with the upgrade.

I don’t know of any way to get Apper or Discover to show the changelogs (but that doesn’t mean there isn’t one; in fact doing the above might work in these tools too).